# C program: multiply two 32 bit value & return in 64-bit on a processor having a 16*16 multiplier

Tags: c, embedded

In a recent interview, I was asked the following coding problem. Could someone please help me understand how to address this problem in terms of C coding?

Q.

- A processor has a 16*16 multiplier to represent 32-bit value.
- Take two 32 bit value, multiply them and return in 64 bit format.

Comment: What have you got so far? Remember your math lessons in school: how did you multiply numbers with multiple digits?

Comment: What is a "16*16 multiplier"?

Comment: @Lundin 16 bits multiplied by 16 bits -> 32 bits

Comment: @Lundin According to elementary school physics, 16 bits multiplied by 16 bits gives 256 square bits, actually. But it is obvious that "16 bits" is short for "a 16-bit number"

Comment: The answer is the C compiler generates the code for you.  The underlying hardware is irellevant.  Given `int32_t x, y ;` Then `int64_t z = (int64_t)x * (int64_t)y ;` ; if you gave the answer you accepted in the interview, I wouldn't hire you.  If the question was how would the compiler generate code to do it, then that would be a different matter - but as an interviewer I wouldn't ask such a question, and if it were asked of me, I might not want to work for that employer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call the 32 bit numbers A and B. Now, let's split them into 16 bit numbers, a0/b0 and a1/b1 (a0 is the bigger part).

Now, `A*B == (a0<<16+a1) * (b0<<16+b1) == (a0 * b0) << 32 + (a1 * b0 + a0 * b1) << 16 + a1 * b1`.

note: All the multiplications here are for 16 bit numbers (a0,a1,b0,b1) with the result as 32 bit number casted into 64 bit (the bigger 32 bits of the number are 0).